# Difference between apache camel and drools

Tags: apache-camel, drools

I want to know what is the difference between camel and drools,and When camel is not a good fit but drools can do!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drools is an engine for business rules, that is take different actions in a process depending on business requirements. Typically chaining together different parts of a business process.

Camel is a routing and mediation engine that works on the integration/transport layer. Mapping message formats between systems, converting protocols (JMS, HTTP, FTP, etc.) and message standards (such as XML, JSON, etc.) as well as routing.